# Azure Devops - cancel pipeline and automatically trigger another

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On my azure devops pipeline, if I cancel / abort the pipeline, is it possible that this can then automatically trigger another pipeline?

For example, I would ideally like a cleanup pipeline to run whenever one of the devs manually aborts the primary pipeline from running.

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

A good approach for this would be using Webhooks resource trigger.

Here's a sample:

1.Create a new Incoming WebHook service connection

[image]

[image]

2.Create a new webhook event:

[image]

[image]

URL: [https://dev.azure.com/{ADO](https://dev.azure.com/%7BADO) Organization}/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/{WebHook Name}?api-version=6.0-preview

3.Define the resource trigger in your target pipeline:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: canceltriggerwebhook           ### Webhook alias
      connection: web1020    ### Incoming webhook service connection
```

4.Test webhook trigger:

[image]

Official doc reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-webhooks-resource